# When creating using a custom rspec matcher in and example group, the message is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm using a custom rspec matcher within a controller spec the message is always empty.

The spec looks like:

```
describe QuestionnaireController do
  matcher :redirect_to_sign_in_if_not_authenticated do |method|
    match do |controller| 
      self.send(method)
      response.should redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it { should redirect_to_sign_in_if_not_authenticated(get :index) }
  end
end
```

When running this test, and it fails, all that comes up is:

```
Failures:

  1) QuestionnaireController GET show
```

As you can see the default should message is missing here.  How do I get it to show up?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `failure_message_for_should` block, as described here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-4/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher#overriding-the-failure-message-for-should

However, you're probably going to run into a few problems here:

- `get :index` will actually call the `get` method, and then pass the return value to the matcher, which the code does not seem to be expecting.
- Errors & backtraces will probably be messed up if you use another matcher (`should redirect_to`) inside your custom matcher.

You might want to consider a shared example instead: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples